# Powerapps Office365Outlook.FindMeetingTimes Error 500

Tags: powerapps

Is there anyone here that currently experiencing with the Office365Outlook.FindMeetingTimes function in powerapp?

The function works fines until today when  I test again my app. I did not change or modify anything as I run my app and then it prompted me with the "Office365Outlook.FindMeetingTimes failed" {error code:500}..."
[image]
Thank you.